# The 'google-api-python-client' distribution was not found on running EXE compiled by pyinstaller | frozen importlib._bootstrap

Tags: python, api, pyinstaller, google-api-python-client

Good day,

I know this question has been asked before, and yes I have tried them. I will first describe the issue before explaining what I have tried:

My python program uses Google Sheet API to read write and modify a spreadsheet.
I am trying to convert my Python file into EXE.
My PyInstaller is 4.2
Python is 3.9

My initial code is as follows:
[image: Python Imports]

To convert to EXE, I used:

```
pyinstaller --onefile LedgerConverterHuobi.py
```

I got the below error:

[image: Error]

This error is after I have tried the following:

1. Downgrade client to 1.8.0

   python -m pip install google-api-python-client==1.8.0

[image: python-client==1.8.0]

2. easy_install google-api-python-client
3. pip3 install --upgrade oauth2client
4. Manually Download client 1.8.0 and put in BUILD folder
5. Run as Administrator

What does frozen importlib._bootstrap mean?

I am currently out of ideas on what else to do.
Any help is greatly appreciated

Kind Regards,
Vokofe

Answer (score 0):

Resolved.

I use this software auto-py-to-exe

https://dev.to/eshleron/how-to-convert-py-to-exe-step-by-step-guide-3cfi